# Flutter - Unable to detect/identify Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-studio-3.0

Just a day ago, [Flutter](https://flutter.io/), a new hybrid (mobile apps) development framework released by Google Inc.

I installed Flutter SDK, following steps, provided from this link: [Install on macOS - iOS setup](https://flutter.io/setup-macos/).

In the same steps, they provided a terminal command `Run flutter doctor` to ensure, Flutter is installation and integration with Android Studio Editor.

Problem is, I've installed Android Studio - 3.0.1 in my mac (macOS - HighSierra) system. But `Run flutter doctor` shows `[✗] Android Studio (not installed)` in result.

What's missing here?

[image]

Comment: see if $ANDROID_HOME is set. If not, then set it to the installation directory of android studio

Comment: Can you please provide more detail by posting your answer with steps, how can I set Android Studio directory path for flutter or vice versa.

Comment: `$ANDROID_HOME` is the path of the SDK, not the Android Studio folder, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not on macos so don't know how things work in that.

Basically you need to export an environment variable. From your shell's config file do the following:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/my/android/studio/installation/dir
```

If your shell is bash, then put the above line in `.bashrc` file in your home directory and either `source .bashrc` or restart the terminal.

That's how I fixed it on linux

Comment: `ANDROID_HOME` it's usually the SDK path, right? Was that path you used?

Comment: Should run `flutter config --android-studio-dir=/my/android/studio/installation/dir`

Answer (score 4):

In my case; i dragged app icon to terminal and finally found out that Android Studio's path is **/Volumes/Android\ Studio\ 3.5.3/Android\ Studio.app**. Then in terminal i typed this and it worked:

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir=/Volumes/Android\ Studio\ 3.5.3/Android\ Studio.app
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue on my MacOS (Catalina). 
I didn't have the Dart + Flutter plugins installed on Android Studio.

So, I went into: 
Configure -> Plugins -> On the Market, I searched for "Flutter" and added both Flutter and Dart plugins.

After installing them, I run flutter doctor and the warning disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

You should configure android studio directory

**Step to configure**

1. open command prompt
2. Type command flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio" and execute

where "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio" is path of installed Android Studio folder

Comment: This question pertains to the Mac installation, not Windows.