# How does Flutter detect that VSCode is installed?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, visual-studio-code, flutter

I have a portable version of vscode on my Windows PC. I have flutter installed as well. `flutter doctor` does not detect my VS Code. I'm guessing it is because its not installed via an installer. It was just copy pasted into a folder.

How can I tell flutter where my VSCode is and that it is my preferred editor without installing it (since I do not have admin rights on the PC)? I tried `flutter config -h` and it only lists the following options

```
--[no-]analytics            Enable or disable reporting anonymously tool usage statistics and crash reports.
--clear-ios-signing-cert    Clear the saved development certificate choice used to sign apps for iOS device deployment.
--gradle-dir                The gradle install directory.
--android-sdk               The Android SDK directory.
--android-studio-dir        The Android Studio install directory.
```

Comment: do you have vscode's command line available ? it may be what flutter is checking

Comment: Do you mean add vscode binary to path environment variable? It is already added to path.

Comment: just export an envonment variable like `$VS_CODE_HOME` set to the path of vscode. [It works for android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047716/flutter-unable-to-detect-identify-android-studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only look in the default install locations for each platform. You can find the code here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/217b2bdaa18de2bfddf213bc920b1337e77f1be3/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/vscode/vscode.dart#L87-L154

You're not missing out on anything by not having it found, all Doctor does is lists it if it's found and tells you if you're missing the Dart Code extension.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Yeah I can still work with VS Code despite the doc complaining :D

Comment: @Harindaka When you say "complaining" what do you mean? Is it detecting VS Code, but not the extension? I would have expected it to not find either, and therefore be silent about them (we just don't mention VS Code at all if we can't find it).

Comment: Its not detecting VS Code and extension both. But like you mentioned, its not a big deal as I'm able to use both and develop / debug flutter apps using my portable vscode despite the flutter doctor warning.

Comment: FWIW I discovered recently that this detection code had become broken due to the casing of folders for VS Code extensions. This will be fixed in an upcoming Flutter release, so hopefully it will start detecting correctly!